# Can Vapor 4 serve both HTTP and HTTPS requests in the same application?

Tags: swift, server-side, vapor

I have a Vapor 4 app which is successfully serving **HTTPS** requests with no issues.

I would like it to also respond to **HTTP** requests on a custom port number, which will be for providing some back-end control and monitoring hooks that are called by other services on the same server, and won't be publicly reachable.

When I search Google and browse the Vapor docs for how to do this, I only get results for a very old version of Vapor, using a configuration file to specify HTTP/HTTPS server and port configurations.

Does anyone know if this type of configuration be done on Vapor 4?

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but I could be wrong. Deploying your vapor app via nginx with dual protocol would be easier anyway and give you other advantages. See https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/deploy/nginx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Vapor 4 cannot serve different protocols on the same port/application. The easiest way around is to run two instances of the application, one for each. Or just get the internal traffic to use HTTPS.

Another option would be to stick Nginx in front or similar

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to avoid it since it's an extremely low traffic application, but I think handing over all of the TLS and per-port access controls to Nginx sounds like the way to go. Your answer was much appreciated!